# Rotations are acting strange in Godot

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I am making a character controller for an FPS and it has come time to make the mouse look script. The code:

```
public override void _Input(InputEvent @event) {
        if(paused) return;
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(0,0);
        if (@event is InputEventMouseMotion eventMouseMotion) {
            move = eventMouseMotion.Relative;
        }
        
        GD.Print(move[0] + " | " + move[1]);
        body.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), move[0] * msX);
        head.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), move[1] * msY);
    }
```

The Hierarchy:

character
character/body
character/body/head

The movement for the body works fine but the head seems to go upside-down every other time I move the mouse.

Godot 4.1 C#
.NET 8
Mac OSX

I tried
`head.Rotation.Y += (offset)`
`head.Transform.Basis.Rotate((up), (offset)`
-etc...
None of it worked, they all had similar behavior.